# Why can I touch the UI thread after ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: wpf, async-await, deadlock

I am experimenting along the lines of Stephen Cleary's [deadlock example](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

With the following code, I am circumventing the deadlock using `ConfigureAwait(false)` (not a good practice, but just for demonstration):

```
    private Uri uri = new Uri("http://ip.jsontest.com/");

    public async Task WaitABit()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var task = WaitABit();
        task.Wait();
        textbox.Text = "aa";
    }
```

According to my understanding, `ConfigureAwait(false)` prevents the deadlock because the SynchronizationContext is not captured, and thus the continuation can occur on a free ThreadPool thread.

However, as far as I know, a ThreadPool thread cannot touch the UI directly. So how is this working?

Comment: To prevent the deadock simply don't block on `async` code. The article you've linked to makes all of that very clear, read it. You should `await` `WaitABit` instead of blocking on it.

Comment: @JSteward You should read my question better. I know how to `await`, this was just an experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out. The task is free to complete on a ThreadPool thread. This allows the blocking `Wait()` to resume on the same UI thread, and it does not break when it touches the TextBox.